# Can't open .html file with UTF-8

Tags: text, text-editor, encoding, utf-8

how could I change the file encoding using OS X? If I open a file on Windows Notepad I see all the symbols and everything is fine. If I open it using TextEdit or TextWrangler I see only question marks instead of the normal symbols. I tried to save the file as plain text using UTF-8 unicode, but it didn't changed. Any more ideas?

Comment: Yes, preferences is set on UTF-8 both opening and saving documents, but it didn't helped. And yes, there is meta data with UTF-8.

Comment: File sent, @TomGewecke

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this problem was caused by the text being actually encoded as Baltic (Windows) instead of UTF-8.